# Overriding - reducing visibility of a method as private, eclipse error

Tags: java, eclipse, overriding

```
public class First {
    public void methodOne() {
        System.out.println("in Parent methodOne");
    }

    public void methodTwo() {
        System.out.println("in Parent methodTwo");
    }
}

public class Second extends First{
    private void methodOne() {
        System.out.println("methodOne");
    }

    @Override
    public void methodTwo() {
        System.out.println("methodTwo");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        First first = new Second();
        first.methodOne();
    }
}
```

Here in the Second class , We have a private method "methodOne". This shows an error in eclipse as "Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from First".
I know this error is because *overriding method should not reduce the visibility*

**Even though that it shows a compilation error, it executes fine and gives the output as `in Parent methodOne`**. If it is a compilation error, why it is producing the output?

When i change the access specifier to protected, it gives the expected compilation error in the console!

Comment: I doubt that you actually ran the newest class of the `Second` class. Maybe, can you try to clean the project and then re-run the class again and see what will happen

Comment: @ThanigaiArasu Kindly read the question completely. Question is about even though it is showing compilation , it executes and gives an output!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Eclipse has implemented its own compiler called as Eclipse Compiler for Java (**ECJ**) by following Java Language Specifications(**JLS**).
- This compiler can **create** **CLASS files even in presence of compilation errors**. However, in the case of serious errors (for example, references to inconsistent binaries, most likely related to an invalid build path), the Java builder does not produce any CLASS files.

If you check Class `Second` 
using `decompiler` ,`methodOne` will be as below

```
          private void methodOne()
              {
                throw new Error("Unresolved compilation problem: \n\tCannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from First\n");
              }
```

Since Reference is of parent class and method is visible ,the parent method gets called.

Eclipse compiler identifies `methodOne` is overridden method of parent and should follow overridden  methods rules.

[Java builder concepts -Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-java-builder.htm)

Comment: i have tried with command prompt. The scenario mentioned in the question results in a compilation error as expected. It is because of the eclipse as stated in this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I could recreate the issue in **Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.7.0.RELEASE**.
Although there is an error pending, when forced to run although there are errors, the **in Parent methodOne** output occurs. Eclipse may be ignoring the error code block, since it is forced to execute.

I executed the following code,

```
 class First {
    public void methodOne() {
        System.out.println("in Parent methodOne");
    }

    public void methodTwo() {
        System.out.println("in Parent methodTwo");
    }
}

 public class Second extends First{
//    private void methodOne() {
//        System.out.println("methodOne");
//    }

    @Override
    public void methodTwo() {
        System.out.println("methodTwo");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        First first = new Second();
        first.methodOne();
    }
}
```

and I got **in Parent methodOne** as the output.

In the code you're assigning the object to a reference of it's parent.

```
First first = new Second();
```

Since the class `Second` doesn't have a method as `methodOne`, the `methodOne` method in the `First` class is called.

Assume you declare the `methodOne` in the second as `Public`.

Then you would get **methodOne** as the output.

When overriding,

- Access to static fields, instance fields and static methods depends on  the **class of reference variable** and **not  the actual  object**  to which  the variable points to.
- This is  opposite of  what  happens in  the case of  instance methods.
  In  case of instance methods, the method in  the **actual  class of  the object**  is called.

Consider the following example.

```
    class ABCD {
        int x = 10;
        static int y = 20;

        public String getName() {
            return "ABCD";
        }
    }

    class MNOP extends ABCD {
        int x = 30;
        static int y = 40;

        public String getName() {
            return "MNOP";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.out.println(new MNOP().x + ", " + new MNOP().y);

      ABCD a = new MNOP();
      System.out.println(a.x); // 10
      System.out.println(a.y); // 20
      System.out.println(a.getName()); // MNOP
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think thats the "magic" of the Eclipse Compiler, it tries to compile it anyway.

This Example runs fine, since at runtime, the buggy Method `compileError`  never gets called:

```
public class EclispeCompilerErrorExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(false) {
            compileError();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("But run anyways");
        }
    }

    private static void compileError() {
        int i = "this wont comppile";
    }
}
```

Your example with `private` works, since your Method never get called (its a private Method, inaccessible for the `First`-Object-Reference), so the `First.methodOne` gets called. When its `protected` ists actually "reachable" for the code, and therefore throw an Exception.

Answer (score -2):

If u wanna override a method in the sub class,the scope of the specified method modifier in the sub class must greater than the base class.
Just like ur programe,the method methodOne's modifier in the class Second must be public.

Comment: The OP understands the problem. They want to know why it compiled, even though it had an error